# How to get content omitting the required tags content

Tags: selenium-ide

```
<span style="background-color: transparent;">
$399.95
<div class="youSave">You Save 36%</div>
</span>
```

I need to get only the value $399.95.But I am getting the text "you save 36%".I tried with "assertelementpresent" but it not working for me as it is showing both the values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `text()` function of Xpath. It get text of under element directly without any other sub-element text.

```
<tr>
    <td>assertText</td>
    <td>//span/text()</td>
    <td>yourExpectedValue</td>
</tr>
```